# What's the solution for this gtk warning?

Tags: c, gtk, warnings

```
GtkWidget *textview;
...
textview = gtk_text_view_new ();
...
buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (textview);
```

At the last line I pasted I got this warning:

```
warning C4133: 'function' : incompatible types - from 'GtkWidget *' to 'GtkTextView *'
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Um use a pointer to GtkTextView instead of a pointer to GtkWidget?

Answer (score 2):

In GTK/GLib/GObject, each class has a typecast macro (the name of the class in uppercase, with underscores) which also checks that the object is of the requested class. Also, most constructors in GTK return `GtkWidget *` pointers, so you have to cast them.

Either of these will work:

1.

```
GtkWidget *textview;
textview = gtk_text_view_new();
buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textview));
```

2.

```
GtkTextView *textview;
textview = GTK_TEXT_VIEW(gtk_text_view_new());
buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(textview);
```